# Best way to change XML root node (name + namespace) with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, stream

I want to change the root node and the namespace in an XML document programatically in C#. I've come across a couple of different solutions that mostly use `XmlDocument`.

The most common solution is to load the entire document in memory, replace the rood node and then set the `InnerXml` to the `InnerXml` of the original root.

It seems a bit stupid to me to load an entire XML document in memory when all you need is exactly one node. This should work practically as fast for any size XML.

Example:

```
<MyDocument xmlns="http://question.stackoverflow.com">
    <AfewKilobytesOfXML />
</MyDocument>
```

Could become:

```
<YourDocument xmlns="http://answer.stackoverflow.com">
    <AfewKilobytesOfXML />
</YourDocument>
```

Best case is that the body of the document is completely ignored and isn't loaded in memory as more than just a stream.

I'd want to provide something I've tried but I don't even know which classes are the best to do this.

The input is a `Stream`. Good to know: the `Stream` might not contain XML at all, so bonus points if your answer has a check for that.

Comment: Side note: I personally think it is bad idea - inserting into stream requires copy (unless you can replace with the same/smaller space-padded text), dealing with encodings manually is not the most pleasant work, generally using string manipulation to construct XML is hard (proper encoding of content, normalization, checks for validity).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I figured that manipulating the stream directly had a few catches, but I was hoping on using classes (preferrably built-in) that did not require actually parsing the entire document and place it all in memory for one silly node. A silly node that is the easiest to find.

Comment: `<AfewKilobytesOfXML />` is trivial to load, even on a phone. Your question is steering towards a String.Replace or RegEx solution, such a bad idea.

Comment: +1 to @HenkHolterman comment - Taking chances on writing correct lower level code to avoid "loading a few K of XML" into memory not worth it in my opinion. Indeed cvraman's suggestion to use `XmlReader` is good and XML friendly one, but I'd not go there for small XMLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid loading the entire xml file into memory, I would say take a look at XmlTextReader and XmlTextWriter. These classes are designed for processing XML files node by node without loading the whole document into memory.

See the various approaches being used in this link : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15278/How-to-Append-to-a-Large-XML-File

Comment: +1. `XmlReader`/`XmlWriter` is good approach for large files and will produce valid XML. Usual drawbacks - it still requires recreating whole files (essentially unavoidable when dealing with updating text in the beginning/middle of a text file) and the API is not exactly most friendly one. Before using that approach make sure size of XML warrants the effort (depending on your circumstances, but I'd say under 100K - use `XDocument` as more people are familiar with that API).